# Yet another “A query body must end with a select clause or a group clause”

Tags: c#, linq, linq-to-sql

This query does work, but I am trying to combine the two steps into one query.

```
var query1 = from b in db.GetTable<Boats>()
             from o in db.GetTable<Offices>()
             from u in db.GetTable<Users>()
             .Where
             (u =>
              u.UserId == b.Handling_broker &&
              o.Office == b.Handling_office &&
              b.Status == 2 &&
              officesToInclude.Contains(b.Handling_office)
             )
             select new
             {
                hOffice = o.Name,
                bName = u.Name
             };

var query2 = query1.GroupBy(t => new { office = t.hOffice, name = t.bName })
          .Select(g => new { Office = g.Key.office, Name = g.Key.name, Count = g.Count() });
```

If I try to combine the two queries using the following query it gives me the “A query body must end with a select clause or a group clause” error.

```
var query1 = from b in db.GetTable<Boats>()
             from o in db.GetTable<Offices>()
             from u in db.GetTable<Users>()
             .Where
             (u =>
              u.UserId == b.Handling_broker &&
              o.Office == b.Handling_office &&
              b.Status == 2 &&
              officesToInclude.Contains(b.Handling_office)
             )
            .GroupBy(t => new { office = t.Office, name = t.Name })
            .Select(g => new { Office = g.Key.office, Name = g.Key.name, Count = g.Count() });
```

I think I have to add a select something, but I can't figure out what.
Can anyone please help?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your query must contain a `select` clause. The `.Where(...).GroupBy(...).Select(...)` are only on the `db.GetTable<Users>()`. Something like:

```
var query1 = from b in db.GetTable<Boats>()
             from o in db.GetTable<Offices>()
             from u in db.GetTable<Users>().Where(u => u.UserId == b.Handling_broker &&
                                                       o.Office == b.Handling_office &&
                                                       b.Status == 2 &&
                                                       officesToInclude.Contains(b.Handling_office))
                         .GroupBy(t => new { office = t.Office, name = t.Name })
                         .Select(g => new { Office = g.Key.office, Name = g.Key.name, Count = g.Count() })
             select new { /* Desired properties */};
```

But I think you are looking for something like:

```
var result = from b in db.GetTable<Boats>()
             from o in db.GetTable<Offices>()
             from u in db.GetTable<Users>()
             where u.UserId == b.Handling_broker &&
                 o.Office == b.Handling_office &&
                 b.Status == 2 &&
                 officesToInclude.Contains(b.Handling_office))
             group 1 by new { t.Office, t.Name } into g
             select new { Office = g.Key.Office, Name = g.Key.Name, Count = g.Count() };
```

Comment: Thanks, that works. Your second version gave me what I was wanted. In the first (dot notation) I can't work out how to get the Count() but the second version is easier to understand.

Comment: @Gerry - the count will be under the `u.` but indeed that is why I added the lower snippet - which explains better what you are doing there